# Any Skin Selector Android library

Tags: android, android-layout

Are there any android library that do:

1. Shows drawables in either a grid or scroll view.
2. Allows user to select one of the images and shows his selection.
3. Allows me to get the selected drawable and show it to the user.

Please see the screenshots to see what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like you are thinking about. I will show you that if is useful to you (I think will be, but you must adapt this):

Context: I have created a simple game based in Space Invaders. My game has a main menu (main activity) where the player can press 'PLAY' or scan elect some 'OPTIONS', though a popup.

[App main menu image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vMyM.png)

**1** screen: Main menu.
**2** screen: Popup appears when I press 'OPTIONS' button. This popup let me choose graphic options (change game background, ally spaceship model and enemy spaship model).

> MainActivity.java

```
optionBoton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        soundMenu.start();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View viewPopup = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_activity, null);
        popup = new PopupWindow(
            viewPopup,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        popup.showAtLocation(layoutPrincipal, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
        ImageButton closePop = (ImageButton) vistaPopup.findViewById(R.id.volver_boton);
        closePop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                soundMenu.start();
                popup.dismiss();
                optionBoton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        optionBoton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
});
```

This code will be inside onCreate method.

Now, you need to design your own XML popup (if you decide to create a popup). Showing a popup is easy, clean and dynamic way to change the graphic options.

> popup_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#839ceaac"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/volver_boton"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/wcerrar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/options_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Opciones gráficas"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/options_title"
        android:background="#9dc8a6" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/options_title"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/back_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:text="Fondo"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/back_1"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/back_title"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:onClick="uploadBack"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/fondo" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/back_2"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/back_1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:onClick="uploadBack"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/fondo1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/back_3"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/back_2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:onClick="uploadBack"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/fondo3" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/spaceship_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:text="Spaceship"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/spaceship_1"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/spaceship_title"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:onClick="uploadSpaceship"
                android:src="@drawable/diseno11" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/spaceship_2"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/spaceship_1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:onClick="uploadSpaceship"
                android:src="@drawable/diseno21" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/spaceship_3"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/spaceship_2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:onClick="uploadSpaceship"
                android:src="@drawable/diseno31" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/enemy_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:text="Enemies"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/enemy_1"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/enemy_title"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:onClick="uploadEnemy"
                android:rotation="180"
                android:src="@drawable/enemigodiseno11" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/enemy_2"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/enemy_1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/enemigodiseno21"
                android:onClick="uploadEnemy"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Anyway, if you choose to don't use a popup, I will show you how you can send some data to another activity in Android development:

1. When you press on a graphic option, look at the call "android:onclick". This allows to call a java method to capture the option selected.
2. Look a simple example of this:

**Method example**

```
public void uploadBack(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.back_1:
            result[0] = "back";
            break;
        case R.id.back_2:
            result[0] = "back1";
            break;
        case R.id.back_3:
            result[0] = "back3";
            break;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have an array of Strings with 3 positions. When I click an ImageView, I call the method wich changes the result[i] value. When I press 'PLAY' and I call the game activity, I use putExtra method to send these options and change the game settings.

I hope this serve as a help for your problem.

Have a nice day!